# NOT SUPPORTED MULTI-GET Enyim Memcached C#

Tags: c#, memcached, enyim

I am currently trying to use the multi Get method proposed by Enyim C# client:

```
Enyim.Caching.MemcachedClient.Get(IEnumerable keys)
```

supposed to return a dictionary of key/result pairs.

Unfortunately, the call eventually returns a not-supported-method exception :-(

It looks very strange that Enyim fails to support this basic feature, has anyone experienced the same unpleasant situation ?

many thanks

register

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, i finally found out what was wrong:

Multi-get is only supported by Enyim with the **binary protocol**, not with the **text protocol**.

register